# How to combine subquery along with INSERT to 2 different tables + referencing auto increment value

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

Here is the query that I would use to find the productID and MAX orderby value

```
 SELECT xc.productid, product, (MAX(orderby)+1)
 FROM xcart_products xp
 LEFT JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xc.productid = xp.productid
 WHERE product LIKE '% Frame'
 GROUP BY productid;
```

I then want to use the productid and the ORDERBY value +1 and populate my xcart_classes table and I'll want to know the auto-increment value that was populated.

```
 INSERT INTO xcart_class_options
 (`classid`,`option_name`,`orderby`,`avail`,`price_modifier`,`modifier_type`,`fba`,`rpro_attr`) 
 VALUES
 ('11434','Yes','0','Y','0.00','$','0',NULL);
 SELECT @last:= LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Then I'll want to use the auto-incremented value to populate the next insert -

```
 INSERT INTO xcart_classes
 (`classid`,`productid`,`class`,`classtext`,`orderby`,`avail`,`is_modifier`,`classnote`,`showcheckbox`,`showcheckbox`,`showaddproduct`,`popup_url`,`popup_width`,`popup_height`) 
 VALUES
 (@last,'<REFERENCEDPRODUCTID>','TEST','TEST','<REFERENCE_MAX_ORDERID+1>','Y','Y','','Y','',NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Was there a way to do both these inserts with one statement or was this something I would need multiple statements for?

Could I save the LAST_INSERT_ID() to a User-Defined Variable to push that to the next insert?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using two separate insert subqueries queries -

```
INSERT INTO rgcart.xcart_class_options 
   (`classid`,`option_name`,`orderby`,`avail`,`price_modifier`,`modifier_type`,`fba`     ,`rpro_attr`) 
    SELECT MAX(classid),'Yes','0','Y','0.00','$','0',NULL
    FROM xcart_classes
    WHERE productid IN (
        SELECT xp.productid
        FROM xcart_products xp
        LEFT JOIN rgcart.xcart_classes xc ON xc.productid = xp.productid
        WHERE product LIKE '% CL'
        GROUP BY productid
        ORDER BY productid ASC)
    GROUP BY productid;

INSERT INTO xcart_classes
(`productid`,`class`,`classtext`,`orderby`,`avail`,`is_modifier`,`classnote`,`showcheckbox`,`showaddproduct`,`popup_url`,`popup_width`,`popup_height`) 
    SELECT xp.productid,'TEST','TEST2',(MAX(orderby)+1),'Y','Y','','Y','',NULL,NULL,NULL
    FROM xcart_products xp
    LEFT JOIN rgcart.xcart_classes xc ON xc.productid = xp.productid
    WHERE product LIKE '% CL'
    GROUP BY productid
    ORDER BY productid ASC;
```